# Finding duplicate values between two arrays using HASHSET

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to create a simple program to find duplicate elements in two arrays. return True if duplicate elements exists else return false.

I have written this much of code but it always returns false.

```
 List<String> list1= new ArrayList<String>();

  list1.add("abc");
  list1.add("xyz");
  list1.add("rst");

 List<String> list2= new ArrayList<String>();

  list2.add("rst");
  list2.add("would");
  list2.add("why");

 Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(list1);
 Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(list2);

 if(set1.contains(set2)){
      System.out.println("exists");
 }else
      System.out.println("doesn't exists");
```

the above code should print "exists" i.e returns TRUE, but it doesn't. Am I missing something badly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding all your elements to `list1` twice, rather than to `list2` in the second instance.  This means that `set2` will be empty, and there will therefore be no intersection between the two.

I'm also very dubious of your use of `HashSet.contains`.  Don't you really want to check for set *intersection*, rather than the existence of a reference to `set2` in `set1`?  That doesn't seem well-typed.  I'd suggest you want to do something like:

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(set1);
intersection.retainAll(set2);

if (intersection.size() > 0) {
    // print true
} else {
    // print false
}
```

Comment: @SJagdeesh Yeah as gian said,without iteration it wont work even now I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking set1 if it contains the entire set2, which it does not. set1 may contain an *element* in set2. You should use a loop or use `retainAll` or `removeAll` and then check if the new size is the same as the old size.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
 for (String string : set2) {
           if(set1.contains(string)){
                 System.out.println("exists");
           }else
                 System.out.println("doesn't exists");
           }
```

**prints** :

```
doesn't exists
exists
doesn't exists
```

Comment: This is objectively a different program to the one that the OP was trying to write, I think.  This will do `n` lookups and write out `n * m` lines of 'exists' or not.  The OP's program output exactly once if *any* element existed.

Comment: @Gian agreed gian I personally tested it.With a single if condition is it possible??

Comment: Yes, it is.  I gave an example of such a condition in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Cehck out Set conatins() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Your code does not check whether each element of `set2` is available or not rather it checks whether `set2` object is available.

If i modify your code like this then it will run fine :

```
     set1.addAll(set2);
     if(set1.containsAll(set2)){
          System.out.println("exists");
     }else
          System.out.println("doesn't exists");
```

To check whether a particular `string` object inside `set2`, one of the solution can be you iterate through it and check individually.